# Removing Fragments within a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to set up a simple ToDo application with multiple "Categories". You can add "Items" to those categories and those categories are shown within a ViewPager that is held in the Main Activity. This illustration should help:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UbOd.png

The problem is with removing categories. I add 3 categories, the first has items "1", "2" & "3" on, the second category has "4", "5" & "6" and the third category has "7", "8" & "9". If I swipe to the second category and then select "delete category" it seems to delete the third category. Only 2 categories are viewable now, the first and second. 
It gets even stranger though. If after I have deleted the category as mentioned above and then click "Add Category" again, another category gets added but it is pre-populated with "7", "8" & "9".  It seems to have cached the third category.
Here is the relevant code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button addItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_item);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.add_cat) {
            adapter.addCategory();
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.delete_cat){
            adapter.deleteCategory(pager.getCurrentItem());
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.addItemToCategory(pager.getCurrentItem());
    }
}
```

MainActivity View:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<CategoryFragment> fragments;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments = new ArrayList<CategoryFragment>();
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void addCategory() {
        CategoryFragment cat = CategoryFragment.newInstance(getCount());
        fragments.add(cat);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteCategory(int idx) {
        fragments.remove(idx);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int itemCount = 0;

    public void addItemToCategory(int currentItem) {
        CategoryFragment catFrag = fragments.get(currentItem);
        ItemFragment itemFrag = ItemFragment.newInstance(itemCount++);
        catFrag.addItem(itemFrag);
    }
}
```

The Item and Category Fragments don't need to be posted here, they are very simple and of little relevance.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my logic here?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I figured it out mostly. I think the problem was that I was caching the fragments I was creating in getItem(). Instead, create a new fragment each time that method is called for a particular argument. The problem seemed to go away.